# How to use eslint with yarn 4.*.* version

Tags: eslint, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use Yarn version 4.*.* version with ESLint, but I'm facing issues running ESLint through the terminal. I suspect this problem arises because ESLint is attempting to search in the node_modules folder and is unable to locate dependencies, yarn 4 and above store them in a different location.

The --resolve-plugins-relative-to option doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

Facing error:

```
ilya@Ilyas-MBP Test % eslint src/

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.56.0

ESLint couldn't find the config "airbnb" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "airbnb" was referenced from the config file in "/Users/ilya/Desktop/Projects/Test/.eslintrc.js".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0",
    "yarn": ">=4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.7",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.7",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.6.7",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.6.7",
    "@types/eslint": "^8",
    "@types/react": "18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "storybook": "^7.6.7",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.18.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import', 'prettier', 'simple-import-sort'],
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  rules: {
    'object-curly-spacing': ['error', 'always'],
    'require-jsdoc': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': ['warn', 'always-multiline'],
    'no-undef': 'error',
    'space-infix-ops': ['error', { int32Hint: false }],
    'max-len': ['error', 180, 2, { ignoreTemplateLiterals: true }],
    'curly': [2, 'all'],
    'no-octal': 'error',
    'no-eval': 'error',
    'no-invalid-this': 'off',
    'prefer-rest-params': 'off',
    'prefer-spread': 'off',
    'no-multi-spaces': ['error', { ignoreEOLComments: true }],
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': ['error', { max: 1 }],
    'no-global-assign': 'error',

    'brace-style': ['error', '1tbs', { allowSingleLine: true }],
    'camelcase': ['error', { properties: 'never', ignoreDestructuring: true }],
    'func-call-spacing': ['error', 'never'],
    'no-array-constructor': 'error',
    'no-unused-vars': ['error', { ignoreRestSiblings: true, args: 'none' }],
    'semi': ['error', 'always'],
    'semi-spacing': ['error', { before: false, after: true }],
    'semi-style': ['error', 'last'],
    'no-extra-semi': 'error',
    'import/no-duplicates': 'error',
    'eqeqeq': ['error', 'always', { null: 'ignore' }],
    'block-spacing': ['error', 'always'],
    'no-shadow': 'error',
    'no-unreachable': 'error',
    'no-unsafe-negation': 'error',
    'no-empty': ['error', { allowEmptyCatch: true }],
    "import/order": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/function-component-definition": ["error", {
      namedComponents: "arrow-function",
      unnamedComponents: "arrow-function",
    }],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.js", "*.jsx", "*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      rules: {
        "simple-import-sort/imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": [
              // Packages `react` related packages come first,
              // Component styles
              ["^react", "^redux", "^.+\\.?(css)$"],
              // Components types, enums
              ["^(types|enums|init|chunks|configs|hooks|helpers)(/.*|$)"],
              ["^@?\\w"],
              // Icons
              ["^.+\\.?(svg)$"],
              // VKUI
              ["^@vkontakte?\\w"],
              // Panels components
              ["^panels(/.*|$)"],
              // Absolute components
              // Parent imports. Put `..` last.
              // Other relative imports. Put same-folder imports and `.` last.
              ["^components(/.*|$)", "^\\.\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\.\\./?$", "^\\./(?=.*/)(?!/?$)", "^\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\./?$"],
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
};
```

When I run `eslint src/` or similar commands, I expect eslint to fix my code